# How to send data from a vert.x server to a js script?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, vert.x

i have a vert.x server and a html page wich send a post request with ajax. I manage to send the post request but i don't understand how to get the answer from the server. My code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:9999',
        data: {d:"hi"}
    }).done(function(data) {alert("succes " + data);})
    .fail(function(data) { alert("fail");})
```

And the vert.x is as follow:

```
httpServer.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("incoming request!");

        if(request.method() == HttpMethod.POST){
            //here i want to do: send to the html page some data
            //like "hi"
        }
    }
});
```

On this link http://tutorials.jenkov.com/vert.x/http-server.html, the autor shows :

```
response.write("Vert.x is alive!");
response.end();
```

But this only displays text on a html page when i connect on localhost:9999 with a browser. I have been on this for hours and i don't know if i do it right.

Can someone help plz ?

EDIT:

Here my start method:

```
     public void start() throws Exception {
        httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
        public void start() throws Exception {
          httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
          httpServer.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {
        System.out.println("incoming request!");

        if(request.method() == HttpMethod.POST){
             HttpServerResponse response = request.response();
                response
                .end();
        }
    }
});

httpServer.listen(9999);
```

Comment: Ty for your answer,
yes i want to do something more specific. In my html page i have a button, when i click on i proceed the post request, and then i want the server to answer me, and in the end i want the callback .done to make a .alert with the data from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistakes, i was using the vert.x the wrong way...
Still thank you for your time Aleksey Bykov.